# understanding tensorflow Recommending movies: retrieval / usage of : in python class /usage of : in python function

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, documentation

I was reading and trying to work with below documentation from tensorflow
https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/basic_retrieval?hl=sl

In this we have implementation of `MovielenseModel` class. Let me provide snippet of same code below

```
class MovielensModel(tfrs.Model):

  def __init__(self, user_model, movie_model):
    super().__init__()
    self.movie_model: tf.keras.Model = movie_model
    self.user_model: tf.keras.Model = user_model
    self.task: tf.keras.layers.Layer = task

  def compute_loss(self, features: Dict[Text, tf.Tensor], training=False) -> tf.Tensor:
    # We pick out the user features and pass them into the user model.
    user_embeddings = self.user_model(features["user_id"])
    # And pick out the movie features and pass them into the movie model,
    # getting embeddings back.
    positive_movie_embeddings = self.movie_model(features["movie_title"])

    # The task computes the loss and the metrics.
    return self.task(user_embeddings, positive_movie_embeddings)
```

In this one usages are not clear and could not find much help in any online documentations

1. Usage of `self.movie_model: tf.keras.Model = movie_model` . Looks like its first class object implementation of function but how does this work? When I simply tried `d:c=3`, just to replicate it worked fine `d` gets value 3 and `c` its saying as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Its an type annotation, check this link here https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html. Here self.movie_model is supposed to be an instance of tf.keras.Model it is very useful and helpful as python is dynamically typed language especially in function / method signatures
you can annotate types of inpuit params and the type of return value